# Cocoa pods with Xcode 8.2.1 and OS X 10.12 Sierra

Tags: ruby, macos, cocoapods, xcode8

after upgrading to OS X Sierra I updated ruby to the last version using rbenv to ruby 2.4.0

```
rbenv version
```

the output is:    `2.4.0 (set by /Users/mohammed.elias/.rbenv/version)`

also update gem system.

then install Xcode command line

```
xcode-select --install
```

and all the things done perfectly.

after that `sudo gem install xcodeproj`

and the gem installed

finally `sudo gem install cocoapods`

and I got this error :

```
Mohammeds-MacBook-Pro:~ mohammed.elias$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:     /Users/mohammed.elias/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
/Users/mohammed.elias/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170108-1398-1ja2y5r.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:     /Users/mohammed.elias/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:     /Users/mohammed.elias/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c

generator.c:861:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cFixnum'
} else if (klass == rb_cFixnum) {
                    ^
generator.c:863:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cBignum'
} else if (klass == rb_cBignum) {


.......... `I deleted some of this`

/Users/mohammed.elias/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2158:12: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_end'
((vari)/(!fmt[ofs] || rb_scan_args_bad_format(fmt)))
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
6 warnings and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in     /Users/mohammed.elias/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to     /Users/mohammed.elias/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0-static/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I proper answer to my question:

uninstall ruby using rbenv which makes you using the system version then reinstall a stable version of ruby using rbenv I updated to ruby version (2.3.3) then install cocoapods `sudo gem install cocoapds`

and everything will be perfect.

Comment: Hopefully this will be fixed soon - there is discussion at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6299